# Is there a way in Powerapps to make sure a column has to be filled in everytime even there is input?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps

I have a question regarding my Powerapps I've built.

With this app user have to update or confirm the data that is stored in a sharepoint list. I have included the "modified by" column to see when someone has updated the data.
My problem is that if the data is up to date and the user submits the form there is no change in the modified by column. Because of that, I can't see if everybody has checked their data.

How can I achieve this even if no changes are made?

I thought of an extra column where the user has to put in something, but I don't know how to keep this empty every time so that the last input won't be shown anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Elena

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow users to submit/confirm without being able to change you can use some logic.

1. The first part of the logic is as normal, let the user submit the form as usual.
2. Make a flow that is being triggered after the normal update that takes the Row ID of your data and for example sets the record to inactive and back to active as this will triggers the modify date to be set.